# Do SQL Server stored procedures run on the database they are installed on or the database they are run from?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Example: I write a stored procedure, let's say `dbo.GetAllColumns`, that selects all of the distinct column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. I install it in database `DevOps`.

Then I run `DevOps.dbo.GetAllColumns` from another database, `TestProc`. Will the output be all of the columns in `TestProc` or all of the columns in `DevOps`?

Comment: Why not test it and see what happens? That would *probably* take less time than posting the question here and waiting for a response.

Comment: DevOps, but I agree with @Igor. Also, if the proc is that simple, you don't need it. You can just write the query with the fully qualified server name as you listed (assuming it's a linked server)

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't and I didn't need the answer urgently but I went ahead and did it. It runs on the database you install it on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case in your question it will return the value from `DevOps` context.

There is a way that you can achieve what you want but I don't recommend it. Best to just install the proc on to all databases that need it.

The way that is similar to your desired behaviour is to create it in `master`, give it an `sp_` prefix and (⚠️ undocumented/unsupported) mark it as a system object.

```
USE master

GO

CREATE PROC dbo.sp_GetAllColumns
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

GO

EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject
  'dbo.sp_GetAllColumns'
```

Now when called from any other database (with `EXEC dbo.sp_GetAllColumns`) it will run in that context.